# Create pins for all items in a JSON file

Tags: ios, json, mkmapview

I am trying to plot a pin in a MKMapView for every coffee shop. I was wondering if there is a way to get that data from the MKMapView. It would say, add a point for every result for "coffee shop" like it would in the apple maps app. The other way I was thinking of doing this was through a JSON file, but I don't have much experience using JSON. Could you tell me a way to use the JSON file or do it the way I listed first.

Comment: Go to json.org and study the syntax.  Takes 5-10 minutes to learn.  iOS has the built-in class NSJSONSerialization to translate to/from JSON.

Comment: SO is more about helping you with something you have tried, than writing something for you from scratch. I suggest searching among the hundreds of questions here for someone who has already tried getting JSON data onto a MKMapView (it does get asked about once a week) and reading up on what those people have already tried.